# Magazines taking submissions for short stories?

Tags: fiction, short-story, magazines

Does anyone have or know of a list of magazines (print or online) accepting submissions for short stories? It would be nice if it could be broken out by genre and payment rates (if applicable).

Comment: related: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/711/is-there-any-hope-of-a-fictional-short-story-being-published

Comment: Since we aren't necessarily going to be able to get a comprehensive list here (that would be one slow-loading question page!), perhaps we want to focus on sources for these lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Duotrope's Digest](http://duotrope.com/) is just that.

Comment: Duotrope is definitely one of the greatest sources.